# Hadoop authentication with Kerberos error

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I am trying to create files in HDFS using:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
```

To do so I add configs like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.set("fs.hdfs.impl",
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName()
);
configuration.set("fs.file.impl",
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName()
);

OutputStream fileout1 = new FileOutputStream("CONF_before.XML");
configuration.writeXml(fileout1);

configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/hdfs-site.xml"));
configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/core-site.xml"));
OutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("CONF_after.XML");
configuration.writeXml(fileout);
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(configuration);

Path out_path = new Path(hdfs.getWorkingDirectory() + "/OD.xml");
OutputStream os = hdfs.create(out_path);
```

When I run this code, I've get an error in `OutputStream os = hdfs.create(out_path)`:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN,KERBEROS]
```

but if I add the `core-site.xml` to a project artefact and run it on a server there are no errors.

The output configurations in both cases are same. Relevant part of `core-site.xml` is:

```
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
```

Any ideas why it happend? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try add this to hdfs-site.xml

```html
<property>
  <name>ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too, and it turned out that:

```
configuration.addResource(new Path("..."))
```

was not loading the file.

I did not traced the cause, but I know that switching to the overloaded method accepting an `InputStream` did work:

```
configuration.addResource(new FileInputStream(new File("...")))
```

You wrote that if you add the XMLs to your JAR resources solves the problem - it is because by default `Configuration` class looks for two XML files in your class path and tries to load them. For quick reference, a fragment of the `Configuration` class implementation:

```
addDefaultResource("core-default.xml");
addDefaultResource("core-site.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a healthy idea. But it doesn't help me. Do I need to configure kerberos ticket?

Comment: The error you are receiving points that property `hadoop.security.authentication` is not set to `kerberos` - like your configuration is not loaded. Print out this property after loading configuration resources and check its value.

Comment: So, the out parametrs after loading configurations is ok(kerberos).